# test documentation with results using doxygen

Tags: unit-testing, doxygen

I used doxygen to generate a test plan describing each test developed.
And I want to include results ( PASS/FAIL) in this documentation.
Is there a way to include results in document generated without changing test files?
For example using a .xls file with results or any other format
Thank you in advance

Comment: Which version of doxygen? The question is very unclear please give an example of what you have and what you want to have.

Comment: I am using doxygen 1.8.11
Basically, the doc generated is a html providing a list of the tests and a descrption for each one.
And I want to add a verdict for each test once run ( pass or fail).

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.11 is quite old (December 30 2015), so an update to the current version (1.9.2) would be in place. The question remains unclear please give an example of what you have and what you want to have. Regarding xls, doxygen does not understand this you could transform it to a HTML or Markdown table and with e.g. `\include{doc}` include this table into the documentation. Another way is that you use `\htmlonly` (and friends) to explicitly write HTML code that is included verbatim. For the mentioned commands see the documentation.